# Laravel search system

Tags: laravel, search

```
   Database
```

---

| product_name | status | product_code | tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 1 | PDT1 | new |
| Product 2 | 0 | PDT2 | new |
| Product 3 | 1 | PDT3 | new |

I want those data where the status is 1. But that code not working properly. It returns all data. Even status is 0. But I want those data where the status is 1. But how can I do this?

```
                 $search_data = Product::where('product_name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                               ->orWhere('tag','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                               ->orWhere('product_code',$search)
                               ->whereStatus(1)
                              ->get();
                  return $search_data;
```

Comment: put where status condition first and add orwhere condition after the status condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud wrap the search inside the where closure.

```
$search_data = Product::query()
        ->whereStatus(1)
        ->where(function($query) use ($search){
            return $query->where('product_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
        ->orWhere('tag', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
        ->orWhere('product_code', $search);
        })->get()
                  return $search_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return Product::Where('status',1)->Where(function($query) use ($search){
$query->where('product_name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('tag','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
    ->orWhere('product_code',$search)
}
->get();
```

Comment: undefined variable $search. vs code editor showing this error...

Comment: @ANWARHOSSAIN updated my ans